# Ask for Permission for Local Notifications in iOS 8, but still have the App Support iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app which uses local notifications. In iOS 7 everything works fine, but in iOS 8 the app needs to ask for user permission to display notifications. To ask for permission in iOS 8 I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

It works fine in Xcode 6 and in iOS 8. When I open the same project in Xcode 5, the error is a Semantic Issue. "Use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationSettings'."

How can I get the app to work with iOS 7 & 8, and have the notifications work properly on both versions.

Comment: Read the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the docs.

Comment: Do you really need to work with both versions of Xcode? Just use Xcode 6 and you can support both versions of iOS.

Comment: Check this link iOS 8 has changed notification registration 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24773465/3560390

Comment: You need to clarify a few things to get the proper answer (so far both are wrong). What is your goal? Do you want a Deployment Target of iOS 7 or earlier AND be able to have a Base SDK of iOS 7 when using Xcode 5 and a Base SDK of iOS 8 when using Xcode 6?

Comment: The project's deployment target is 7.0. While it could compile in Xcode 6 on its own, the app will crash on start up on an iOS 7 device.

Comment: Then see my answer. It supports both iOS 7 and 8 as well as working under both Xcode 5 and 6. The answer you accepted won't work at all even under iOS 8.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following answer makes a few assumptions:

1. The app must build properly with a Base SDK of iOS 8 when using Xcode 6 and it must build properly with a Base SDK of iOS 7 when using Xcode 5.
2. The app must support a Deployment Target of iOS 7 (or earlier) regardless of the Base SDK and Xcode version.

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // None of the code should even be compiled unless the Base SDK is iOS 8.0 or later
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    // The following line must only run under iOS 8. This runtime check prevents
    // it from running if it doesn't exist (such as running under iOS 7 or earlier).
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
#endif
}
```

All of this is covered in the Apple [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

Comment: This is elegant and correct. I found more errors in my answer and no straightforward way to fix them ,so I deleted it.

Comment: You can't release your app based on this solution before Apple release XCode 6.

Comment: @RobertYiJiang But the answer was asked during the beta. The answer is correct and it is what the OP needed (or they wouldn't have accepted it). Downvoting the answer because Apple hasn't yet (but probably today) started accepting apps from Xcode 6 is inappropriate.

Comment: The answer can also be easily adapted for anyone who needs to support iOS 7 and iOS 6, for example. Or in two years time for anyone who needs to support iOS 9 and iOS 7.

Answer (score 11):

I have implemented simply -

```
if([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you still want to compile against older SDKs or have a special reason to do so, you may try calling the whole stuff dynamically:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
#define USING_IOS8_SDK
#else // iOS <8 SDK compatibility definitions
#define UIUserNotificationTypeNone    (0)
#define UIUserNotificationTypeBadge   (1 << 0)
#define UIUserNotificationTypeSound   (1 << 1)
#define UIUserNotificationTypeAlert   (1 << 2)
#endif


...

if ([_sharedApplication respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"registerUserNotificationSettings:")])
{
    NSUInteger settingsParam = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    id categoriesParam = nil;

#ifdef USING_IOS8_SDK

    // Perform direct call when using iOS 8 SDK
    [_sharedApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:settingsParam categories:categoriesParam]];

#else
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

    // Do the dynamic stuff

    // Get UIUserNotificationSettings class reference
    Class settings = NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings");
    if (settings) {

        // Prepare class selector
        SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"settingsForTypes:categories:");

        // Obtain a method signature of selector on UIUserNotificationSettings class
        NSMethodSignature *signature = [settings methodSignatureForSelector:sel];

        // Create an invocation on a signature -- must be used because of primitive (enum) arguments on selector
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        invocation.selector = sel;
        invocation.target = settings;

        // Set arguments
        [invocation setArgument:&settingsParam atIndex:2];
        [invocation setArgument:&categoriesParam atIndex:3];

        // Obtain an instance by firing an invocation
        NSObject *settingsInstance;
        [invocation invoke];
        [invocation getReturnValue:&settingsInstance];

        // Retain an instance so it can live after quitting method and prevent crash :-)
        CFRetain((__bridge CFTypeRef)(settingsInstance));

        // Finally call the desired method with proper settings
        if (settingsInstance)
            [_sharedApplication performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"registerUserNotificationSettings:") withObject:settingsInstance];
    }

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
}
```

This should perfectly compile on iOS 7 SDK and work (effectively) on iOS 8 devices, ignored on older ones.

Migrating your project to iOS 8 SDK is another solution, thought, but there are still options.

Answer (score 3):

So far, this code snippet works for me, and its simple to reuse:

```
//-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: This won't work (it won't compile) when built with Xcode 5 and a Base SDK of iOS 7. That was the whole point of the question. The code needs to build and run whether using Xcode 5 or Xcode 6.

Comment: Your question required the code to work for ios7 and ios8. If you want to compile for ios8 you must use xcode 6.

Comment: It's not my question but read it again. The OP wants to build the app with both Xcode 5 (Base SDK of iOS 7) and Xcode 6 (Base SDK of iOS 8). Your answer won't work with Xcode 5 (Base SDK of iOS 7).

Comment: "How can I get the app to work with iOS 7 & 8, and have the notifications work properly on both versions."
No, this solution won't work for Xcode 5, but if you use xcode 5 you won't be able to compile for ios8.
You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings") != nil) {
    // your iOS 8 code here
    #define isiOS8
}
else {
    #undef isiOS8
}

#ifdef isiOS8
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
#endif
```

It's a bit more convoluted but it works fine.

** EDIT ** Fixed code better

Comment: Neither of those worked in Xcode 5 but they both worked in Xcode 6.

Comment: I still get the Semantic Error. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/s1G3oZb) (I don't know how to upload images into comments)

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Let me think.

Comment: How does this work? the `if (NSClassFromString(` part is a run-time statement (is evaluated at run time), but the `#ifdef isiOS8` is a preprocessor directive (is evaluated at compile time).

Comment: This code won't work at all. It may compile but under iOS 8 it won't register anything because that code won't be compiled in.

Comment: This cannot work, because #define / #undef are evaluated by the pre-processor. The preprocessor sees #define followed by #undef, so isiOS8 will be undefined and registerUserNotificationSettings will not be called.