# Local Notifications Wont Appear - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, uilocalnotification

The app should send a local notification to the user when the app is in the background...

i have followed every tutorial there is, i am doing exactly as the tutorials say and **i dont have any errors after writing the code or warnings** **but the Local notifications still wont appear after trying everything.**

i am using xcode 6, running ios8 on the test device i have even tried running on the simulator and still nothing. please help. i have tried atleast 5 different ways to get local notifications working but still nothing however i have no errors... **what should i add or what arent i doing?**

To test that the fault that this isnt working isnt mine, i have:
**-Tried restarting xcode
-Tried rebooting my device and simulator
-Tried using the code on a new project 
-Tried rebooting my mac**
But still the notifications wont appear... i have a feeling it might be ios8 issue or xcode6 issue

here is the code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[localNotification setFireDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15]];
[localNotification setAlertBody:@"this is a test notification"];
[localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

}

Comment: Try using presentLocalNotificationNow and see if it appears. I'm guessing you have some sort of time zone issue. Is the defaultTimeZone perhaps behind or ahead of what the actual time is where you are?

Comment: The time on the device i am testing with is the same as he time on my mac and using the same TimeZone. i have also tried testing the local notifications on the Simulator but still nothing...

Comment: Did you try presentLocalNotificationNow?

Comment: where should i add that within the code i already have?

Comment: use it instead of scheduleLocalNotification:

Comment: just tried that and run it 4 times but no notification appearing after i press the home button to send the app to background... :(

Comment: check your Notification Setings also… in Notification Center… for your app; also.. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24948048

Comment: @TonyMkenu as i stated above and below i have checked the notification settings nothing there and also tried those other codes in the link you provided but nothing will work... Still no notifications appearing when i put the app in the background

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your didFInishLaunchingWithOptions method in your app delegate:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

In iOS 8, I am not 100% sure but it may be required to put that piece of code before local notifications are allowed to work.

Comment: Go to your settings on your device/simulator and find your app and click on it. There should be a notification label. Are those off?

Comment: i have tried that too... the app i am running doesnt appear under settings-notifications. And the notifications option doesnt appear under the app in settings-appname

Comment: To add on to Millie's answer, I would try removing the setTimeZone completely and see what happens. I never have used a time zone.

Comment: i have just tried that (removing the setTimeZone) still no notification appearing after i press the home button to put the app in background mode

Comment: Wow. Thats weird... This may sound stupid but this is the last thing I can think of. Instead of doing message calls like [localNotification setFireData: ...], try on all of those localNotification.fireDate and etc...

Comment: Doing that gives me errors however i have tried that method too using a different code that doesnt give me errors but even that doesnt work (notification wont appear)

Comment: I am sorry but I am completely out of ideas. I have used local notifications for two of my apps before without any problems. I hope you figure it out! :)

Comment: try to change this line [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]; … in this  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];

Comment: sorry, mistype:  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];

Answer (score 0):

Since the Notifications are changed in iOS 8.0, add this in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    //iOS Version < 8.0 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```