# Push notification showing before background refresh finished (using Push with background refresh)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set up my app so when a push is received it first fetches the new messages before showing the push notification. In my push notification I have content-available = 1 set and also the switches enabled in the Plist. I have implemented:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{

    if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"content-available"]){

        NSLog(@"Doing the background refresh");
        UINavigationController *navigationController=(UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

        MYViewController *MYViewController = (MYViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

        [myViewController.currentUser refreshMessagesArrayWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL successful, BOOL newMiaos) {

            NSLog(@"messages refreshed the array now has %lu messages",(unsigned long)[myViewController.currentUser.messages count]);
            handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

        }];




    }
}
```

The app push will come in before the background finish has finished or during the refresh. Surely it should come in after. Am I dealing with this wrong? Do I need to send a silent push notification instead and show a `local` notification after the completion block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue similar as yours,
I resolved it, by sending a push notification like this

```
{
        "alert": null,
        "content-available": 1,
        "data-id" : "some_data_id"
}
```

In this case push notification will not be displayed,
so in background fetch you can perform fetching and trigger a local notification.

Comment: can a local notification be triggered instantly? also do local notifications require the same permissions as push notifications? My app asks if the user will allow push notifications to be used, this is the same one for local right?

Comment: can a local notification be triggered instantly >> yes, local notification does not require any permission, but you need permission as you are also receiving remote notification.

Comment: ah, sorry. seems on iOS8 local notifications requires some permission, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946650/ask-for-permission-for-local-notifications-in-ios-8-but-still-have-the-app-supp

Comment: That's a bit of a mess no? Having the app ask permission for remote notifications and local notifications....worried it would put users off..

Comment: I think it's the same permission. If you are covered for remote push notifications then you are covered for local too.

Comment: how can you pass a string though also? alert used to contain my string but now it is null. I have tried adding "someMessage":pushMessage to the payload but when I receive the push and try to get the string using NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"someMessage"] I get null. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to get `data-id`, then request to your backend and get the message.

Comment: what is the data-id? checked the apple docs in APN and couldn't see anything about it