# How to handle push notifications depending on iOS version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

For iOS7, Parse handled push notifications with the following code in AppDelegate:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

`registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` isn't supported in iOS8 however, and the new code used to handle push notifications in iOS8 now looks like this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                  categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Using this new code with an iOS7 device causes the app to crash, so I need to have the code determine which version the phone is on, and run the appropriate push notification code. How can I have the app check this, and use the correct one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always better to check the availability of methods, rather than OS version.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]) {

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Assuming your deployment target is >= 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later)

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: The best way to not take credit for that is to add a comment with a link to the other question. Or, better yet, flag this question as a duplicate.