# xamarin registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: push-notification, xamarin, ios8

I'm using Xamarin to develop my iOS apps, but with the release of iOS 8, I'm having problems with registering for Push Notifications. I get the following error with the code that was written under iOS 7 SDK:

**registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.**

I know that instead of using "**RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes()**", which has been depreciated, I need to use "**registerUserNotificationSettings**" & "**registerForRemoteNotifications**".

The following link would have helped it it was in C# using Xamarin Libraries: 
[registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later)

I have looked for those Methods under "UIApplication.SharedApplication." but can't find them...am I looking in the wrong spot? (I have targeted iOS 8 in my build setup).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
    UIUserNotificationType.Alert 
    | UIUserNotificationType.Badge 
    | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, 
    new NSSet());
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
```

Comment: Turns out that RegisteredForRemoteNotifications will only be called once in my observations. It would be wise to save the device token on both the device and your server.