# IOS 8 push notification check returns wrong UIRemoteNotificationType

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, ios8

I'm trying to check if PushNotifications for my app are enabled.

In AppDelegate.m I do register app for remote notifications, and in Settings on iPhone (iOS 8) Push Notifications for this app are enabled.

I've googled to methods:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

BOOL check = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

As the result, *types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone and check = NO*.

I'm using this [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later) to register application for Push Notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    //-- Set Notification
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) 
    {
           // iOS 8 Notifications
           [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

           [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
          // iOS < 8 Notifications
          [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

     //--- your custom code
     return YES;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you've already found a solution but just in case: in iOS 8, enabledRemoteNoficationTypes is deprecated you should use:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        if (currentSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {}
```

Best

Comment: Thank you it solve my problem. It will detect if user turn off the notification.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking your state with this code:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType allOnType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge ;
UIRemoteNotificationType offType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone ;

UIRemoteNotificationType currentTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

if (currentTypes == allOnType) {
    // all are on
} else if (currentTypes == offType) {
    // all are off
} else {
    // some are on, some are off
}
```

**Edit**

Also, try implementing the Push Notification Callbacks:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSLog(@"Token%@",deviceToken);    
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"err:%@",err);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //for iOS8
}
```

Comment: This code goes to "all are off" condition. Obviously because [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]; returns UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone as I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: How do you register for remote notfications. I'm pretty sure you don't get a wrong response. Your app is simply not configured correctly for push

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that if there are correct notification settings for app in iPhone Setting menu, app is configured correctly. Added registration code to question

Comment: Has to be *iOS 8* compatible, this was deprecated in iOS8