# iOS Push Notifications Working on iOS 8 But Not on iOS 7 (Using 8.1 SDK)

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

After upgrading to Xcode 6.1 and using iOS 8.1 as the Base SDK, I added the conditionals below to support the push notifications in both iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

The push notifications work fine for iOS 8 but not anymore for iOS 7. Normally, when the app starts up, the user is asked to allow or disallow push notifications in the app. (I reset the simulator at every launch to ensure that the alert view comes up and also check in Settings to see if the app is listed there). The alert view comes up only in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7. This applies to both the simulator and the physical device.

When I put a break-point and step through the code, the 'else' part gets executed but the alert view does not come up, nor does the app appear in Settings.

I am using Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.1 as Base SDK and the iOS Deployment Target is 7.1. I am really stuck here because this means dropping push notification support in my app for iOS 7.1. Perhaps this came about as part of the 8.1 SDK?

Anyone faced a similar issue or does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Might be obvious, but how come you're using `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` everywhere else, but inside the iOS < 8 block, you're using `application`?

Comment: Typo. I've updated it now. In my code, it's ```[UKApplication sharedApplication]```

Comment: Simulator alert for Push Notification is iOS 8 only. Make sure the delegate API's are called in code when running for iOS 7.x by adding breakpoints/NSLog.

Comment: You are correct about the simulator alert coming up for iOS 8 only. I just got it tested on another device running iOS 7.1.2 and everything worked fine.

Comment: i have same problem, how do you solve your problem ?

Comment: My problem was specific to that device which had the older version of the app installed previously (and removed later; that older version had the same name but different bundle ID / app ID). It is best to test it on a device instead of a simulator. A few things to check: (i) Does the prompt asking the user to allow/disallow push notifications come up? (ii) Does the app appear in Settings/Notifications? (iii) Is the device token obtained? (iv) Is the device token sent to the server? (v) Is the feedback service running on the server on a regular basis to prune the invalid/inactive device tokens?

Comment: I don't think you can test push notifications in the simulator

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Of the checklist I have mentioned in my previous comment, in my case the fifth item was the main cause.When the server code starts sending notifications to devices one after another in order, APNS will stop (and will not skip) as soon as a notification is sent to an invalid/inactive device token.  Once that offending device token was removed, it was resolved.

Please also go through the checklist to verify everything else is working.