# ios 10 Notifications click does nothing

Tags: ios, swift

My code for notification execution is present in `didRecieveRemoteNotification` method in `AppDelegate`. 
When a notification comes and is clicked on, the action is performed in `iOS9` and `iOS8`, but in `iOS10` nothing happens. On clicking the `notification` the app just opens.

I know this can be fixed with the new functions available in `Xcode8` but what is the reason it is not working here?

I have seen some other apps, whose notifications work in `iOS10` properly

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-being-called-when-i-tap-on-notification-on-ios/39383027#39383027

Comment: I know it works with the new functions, but why not with the old ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/169625#169625. 
Apparently, iOS 10 doesn't call the method:

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

Instead, it calls

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```