# can I built app (xcode 7.3.1 objective C) on iOS 10 ? or any other solotion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, xcode7.3

I have created an application in xcode 7.3.1 (Objective C) and want to run this app on my device **iOS10** it is possible?

Comment: (My previous comment was unwarrantedly [sic] snarky.  My apologies.)  You can't use Xcode 7.3 to install and debug on iOS 10 devices.  Apps built with Xcode 7.3 can be installed through Ad-hoc or App Store builds.

Comment: Not, you are check your application that create ipa and upload third party for test ipa and download your device.

Comment: @Avi thanx for answer.. if i install xcode 8.0 and move my project on this than any issue?

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya can i move my project on xcode 8.0 ?

Comment: yes, but push notification you set that some issue occur. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: ok there is no pushnotification for my app thanx @BhadreshKathiriya

Comment: @seggy It will be better to download xCode 8 it will allow you to debug the code. Please check my answer.. Option 1) & 2) is fast solution but 3) will work for long run.

Comment: No You cannot.You need OS Captain 10.11.6 os version to run xcode 8 GM to debug apps on IOS 10 SDK

Comment: @seggy you can tick my answer It will help other SO user to search and resolve similar kind of option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of option for your application to run in **iOS 10**.

1) you can build ipa and upload on any third party service (e.g https://www.diawi.com/)

2) Create AdHoc/AppStore Build

3) Download `Xcode8` and migrate your app to new `Xcode`. This will be better as you can debug your application code if you choose this option.

**Note** : For [Download](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) `Xcode8` you need to upgrade your `OSX` to 10.11.4

For Option 1 & 2 you can not debug your application code.

Hope this will be helpful !!!

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 7.3.1 cannot install applications on iOS 10. To do that from Xcode you need to upgrade to Xcode 8 and macOS 10.11.

You can upload your app to the app store and install it using TestFlight. Or you can create a Hockey account and download it using the Hockey app.

Comment: ohk but if move my project to xcode 8.0 than any issue?