# How to implement push notification for iOS 10[Objective C]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, appdelegate, nsusernotification

Can anyone help me with implementing push notification for iOS 10 as i have implemented following code but still getting problem in it:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0"))
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
        if(!error){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }];
}
else {
    // Code for old versions
}
```

I am getting error suggesting that

> Unknown receiver UIUserNotificationCenter

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sorry guys, I got the answer.
I just needed to import **UserNotifications** framework.

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Check this**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
```

**Then**

```
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];
#endif
    }
```