# iOS 10 Request Notification Permission fires twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, push-notification, ios10

When I launch my app on **iOS 10**, I get the request *notification permission* twice.
The first one briefly appears and disappears immediately without allowing me to do any actions, then I got the second popup with a normal behaviour waiting for *"allow"* or *"deny"* from the user.

Here is my code that worked well before **iOS 10**.

In the method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** from the ***AppDelegate*** :

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

Should I implement something for iOS 10 in order to fix this double request permission ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For iOS 10 we need to call the UNUserNotificationCenter in appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

**First we must import the UserNotifications framework and add the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in Appdelegate**

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]<10.0)
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
   else
   {
      UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
      center.delegate = self;
      [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
      {
         if( !error )
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
             NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
             NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );  
         }  
     }];  
   }
  return YES;
}
```

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027)

Comment: be extra careful with the suggested code. In the callback you are assuming that `!error` means user has granted permissions for notifications and that is not true. If user refuses to receive notifications, you will receive a `granted = NO` and `error = nil`, breaking your logic.

Comment: It is a bad practice to check API availability like this. Consider using `[UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil` and `respondsToSelector:` methods.