# Is it mandatory to use UNUserNotificationCenter to get push notification in iOS10

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10

Is it mandatory to use UNUserNotificationCenter implementation with the following code to get(make work) push notification in iOS10 ?

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
        if (granted)
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else{
            //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
        }
    })
}
```

Or is it just enough to just make the following to receive push notification to the existing app ?

- Import UserNotifications.framework
- Under "Capabilities"

  - Turn on "Push Notification"
  - Check "Remote Notification" checkbox under "Background Modes"

And please official documentation denoting this if any.

Comment: frst one is manodatry

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Anbu I have edited my question, could you please let me know wether that part of code is mandatory to make notification work in iOS 10

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027