# Silent push notification not working in background mode ios 10

Tags: swift3, ios10

The silent push notification behaviour is very strange in ios 10.1.1. I tried all possible ways to setup properly like adding extension and frameworks but still i am facing weird issue. When the push notification is fired from server it goes properly but on receiver side in device its not wake up the device and after that when i try to reopen my application than i received the remote notification delegate event. so my question is does apple stop support for silent mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)