# iOS 10 Push Notification Tap Handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am implementing Push Notifications the iOS 10 way and not able to figure out how would I intercept user's tap on the notification banner. None of the delegate call back gets called when user tap on the banner both in background and foreground mode. This looks more of an API issue in iOS SDK itself.

Anyone experienced the same and have a work around? Please let me know.

Comment: see this once may be u get option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, below delegate call back gets called when user tap on the notification. I had implemented specific actions on the notification banner and was putting a check on those action identifiers and completely missed the user tap :).

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)iCenter didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)iResponse withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())iCompletionHandler
```