# What is difference between Any , Hashable , AnyHashable in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, associated-types, hashable

I scratch my head through lots of tutorials to understand the difference between the above 3 terms and find new term `type erased` container, now it becomes confusing to me. It raises lots of question.

Why does Swift introduce `AnyHashable` ?

What is the fundamental difference between these 3 terms?

Difference between `Any` and `AnyHashable` ?

Difference between `Hashable` and `AnyHashable`?

When to use `Hashable` and when to use `AnyHashable` ?

Last but most confusing, what is the meaning of `type erased` term in the context of `AnyHashable` ?

As a context, I followed [Swift Evolution Proposal SE-0131](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0131-anyhashable.md).

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's more important to understand what they are than what are the differences between them.

`Any` means "anything", ranging from swift enums, tuples, closures, structs, classes, protocols, whatever. Every type can be assigned to a variable of type `Any`.

`Hashable` is protocol that says "this object can be hashed i.e. has a hashcode". If your object can be hashed, implement this protocol, because lots of data structures (namely dictionaries and sets) need it.

So what is `AnyHashable`?

Normally, if you try to do this:

```
let a: Set<Hashable>?
```

it does not compile. This is because `Hashable` inherits from `Equatable` which contains `Self`.

Now, let's say you want to port a method from Objective-C to swift. That method takes a parameter of type `NSSet`. In Swift, this will turn into a `Set`, but what is its generic parameter? If we just put `Any` like we do with `NSArray`s, it does not work because `Set`'s objects must be hashable. But if we put `Set<Hashable>` it does not work either because `Hashable` can only be used as a generic constraint. That's why they wrapped `Hashable` with an `AnyHashable` that *does not* use `Self` and so can be used as a generic parameter.

Regarding what "type erased" means:

Having `Self` in a protocol is kind of [like a protocol with a generic parameter](https://github.com/slavapestov/swift/blob/97cf3e6626a0b8af76b1558faf2ab95ed1e0d815/include/swift/AST/Decl.h#L3876), and the generic parameter is always the conforming class. This causes the protocols to be unable to be used on its own like `Set<Hashable>` because the "generic parameter" is unknown. `AnyHashable` solves this problem by not using `Self` at all so it now becomes a normal struct. It "erases" the generic `Self` type.

Comment: Everything understood, other than  `type erased` term, I am trying to understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand about `type erased`? @technerd

Comment: Honestly, type erasing seems strange for me. I am trying to understand from this example.https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/

Comment: @technerd Try reading this: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/

Comment: @technerd think about AnyHashable as about a box which encapsulates Any which conforms to Hashable protocol. See http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/AnyHashable/

Comment: @Sweeper: I will surely check bignerdranch. Thanks

Comment: @technerd A good meta discussion can be found at: [bugs.swift](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9403)