# Swift: "Type 'any Hashable' cannot conform to 'Hashable'"

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I'm a bit confused by an error I'm seeing in the new Xcode beta around the new `any` syntax in Swift.

I have a view that takes an `any Hashable`, and I'm trying to pass that to a parameter that takes a `Hashable` parameter. However, I get this error from Xcode: `Type 'any Hashable' cannot conform to 'Hashable'`. I can't see why this should be, as I thought an `any Hashable` is essentially a type-erased Hashable, right?

Here's a full code sample to illustrate what I'm trying:

```swift
struct AwesomeNavigationLink: View {
    var itemToLinkTo: any Hashable
    var label: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: itemToLinkTo) {
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the above error on the NavigationLink line.

My questions are: Should I be able to pass a `any Hashable` to a `Hashable`? If so, how, or is this a bug? If not, why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the latest version of Swift/Xcode, that is an error also: "Use of protocol 'Hashable' as a type must be written 'any Hashable'"

Comment: Yeah I wondered if it was a bug but thought I'd make sure I wasn't missing something first. I'll reframe the question slightly as "should it be possible" to make this a bit clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates I'm running into a similar situation with the new `NavigationSplitView`

Comment: `any` is _NOT_ a magic type eraser. `any X` means exactly the same as what `X` used to mean, no more and no less. A protocol cannot conform to itself.

Comment: You need to provide concrete type at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler error you saw leaves the problem a bit unclear. In the question you stated that `any Hashable` is a type-erased `Hashable`. However, the signature of the `NavigationLink` `init` uses a generic and requires the `value` to be a very specific type instance that is `Hashable`. That means the type of `itemToLinkTo` has to be known at compile time to be passed into the init and `any Hashable` is literally anything that can be hashed which is not enough for the compiler.
A solution could be to make your view generic too with

```
struct AwesomeNavigationLink<Link: Hashable>: View {
    var itemToLinkTo: Link
    var label: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: itemToLinkTo) {
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}
```

That moves the type problem upwards. At some point it must be clear and hence explicitly defined of what type `itemToLink` is though.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this Answer by @technerd help

Hashable contains self where AnyHashable not

Having Self in a protocol is kind of like a protocol with a generic parameter, and the generic parameter is always the conforming class. This causes the protocols to be unable to be used on its own like Set because the "generic parameter" is unknown. AnyHashable solves this problem by not using Self at all so it now becomes a normal struct. It "erases" the generic Self type.

you can read the full comment here [Difference between Any, Hashable, AnyHashable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44513859/2815090)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm referring to the new `any SomeProtocol` syntax - the answer you've posted refers to the situation prior to this keyword being introduced. The any keyword already introduces type erasure, so the associated type shouldn't be an issue

Comment: "The any keyword already introduces type erasure" No it doesn't.