# center didReceiveNotificationResponse not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, push-notification

I have implemented the push service many times even right now its working i am able to receive the notification but don't know why method below is not getting called

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

I googled and tried to find the solution, then I came across the things that all are already there in my code, but still I am facing this problem, I need you coders help is any thing that we could miss for this issue, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: @iShwar your issue resolved? can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

This method is a delegate method. So to get this called,  you have to implement the delegate of **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** in the header file. If you have forgot to use delegate, place it in header file. The example below shows to place delegate for a UIViewController of name ViewController in header file:

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

And in the method or implementation file(ViewController.m), in its method **viewDidLoad**, place

```
self.userNotificationCenter.delegate = self;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: `[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;` did it in my case :)