# How to get push notification when app is in active state in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I am working on an app in which I have implemented apple push notification. When my app is in background state then I am able to receive push notifications but when my app is in active state then I am not able to get any push notifications, can anypne help on this?

Comment: could you please share some code, so that it is easy for anyone to help

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: my push notifications service is not working for ios device but its working for android.. can any tell me what will be the issue? and were i went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

delegate method to receive remote notification in all state.

If you want to show the notification alert in active state. use `HDNotificationView`  to show notification alert.

like this:

```
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

[HDNotificationView showNotificationViewWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-40.png"]
                                                            title:title
                                                          message:message
                                                       isAutoHide:YES
                                                          onTouch:^{
                                                              /// On touch handle. You can hide notification view or do something
                                                              [HDNotificationView hideNotificationViewOnComplete:nil];
                                                          }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `UIAlertView` inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and check if you are receiving notification in `active state`. Check below code

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  {

        if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {                              
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Received a Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My App received  notification while it is running:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];          
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When Push Notification received to your app Application can be one the below 5 states **Reference**:: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

**1)Not running**

**2)Inactive**

**3)Background**

**4)Suspended**

**5)Active**

If application state is 1,2,3,4 then iOS will handle and will display banner 
In case of 5(Active state) our app needs to handle this case 
In this case below method will be called

**Reference**:: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
```

here you need to check state of app using application.state == Active then you can do what ever you want ideal case here we need to display alert .