# iOS 10.0 * Handle Push notification in foreground

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

If i implement the method to present push notification in ios 10.0

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)

    }
```

then it present all the notification , 
So, my question is how can i prevent to show particular push notification like (login at another deveice ) i just handle code for that particular push only

Comment: see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My push data is

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "id" : 2091
        },
        "sound" : "chime.aiff"
    },
    "acme" : "foo"
}
```

I have used id because i can separate each push by its id, and based on id i can decide weather to show notification in foreground or not..

Thanks @Anbu.Karthik For reference 
as per my question we can handle push even user did't tap on notification in

```
   @available(iOS 10.0, *)

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        print("Handle push from foreground")
        let userInfo:[AnyHashable:Any] =  notification.request.content.userInfo
        let aps:NSDictionary = (userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary)!
        let alert:NSDictionary = (aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary)!
        let id = Int(alert["id"] as! Int)
        if id == your id
        {    
         //Handle push without prompting alert 
        }

        else
        {
          //Display alert
         completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
        }
    }
```

And When user tap on notification Following method is called...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        print(userInfo)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation:

> // The method will be called on the delegate only if the application
>   is in the foreground. If the method is not implemented or the handler
>   is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be
>   presented. The application can choose to have the notification
>   presented as a sound, badge, alert and/or in the notification list.
>   This decision should be based on whether the information in the
>   notification is otherwise visible to the user.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler __IOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0);
```

So to answer your question, if you want to prevent the notification from being shown, either do not implement this method or do not call the handler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my question is about when app is in foreground, And i want to prevent particular notification not all

Comment: In that case, you can check the notification payload and then do not call the handler if you want to hide a particular notification.