# Dock or control center does not make application inactive

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios11, uiapplication

When I open navigation drawer application.ApplicationState should be Inactive but in iOS 11 it is Active.

I want to detect if application: didReceiveRemoteNotification was called by tapping on a notification in Notification Center

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let state : UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if (state == .Inactive || state == .Background) {
        // go to screen relevant to Notification content
    } else {
        // App is in UIApplicationStateActive (running in foreground)
    }
}
```

Is it a bug in iOS 11 or is there new approach with Push Notifications?

Other way to check applicationState:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    var app = application.applicationState
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: In my case didReceiveRemoteNotification is called. In iOS 10 everything works well.

Comment: ios10.x it should not work

Comment: Why it should not work? I have an application which works properly in iOS 10. Now I tested my app in iOS 11.9 Beta and faced this issue.