# Swift NotificationCenter not receiving post

Tags: swift, post, nsnotificationcenter, observers, notificationcenter

I am trying to send a notification when a user re-signs in with Apple.

I have three parts:

1. Extension:

> ```
> extension Notification.Name {
>     static let userSignedIn = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userSignedIn")
> }
> ```

2. Post Notification:

   ```
       if let userIdentifier = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "appleSignIn") as? (String) {

                      let authorizationProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
                      authorizationProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: userIdentifier) { (state, error) in
                          switch (state) {
                          case .authorized:
                            print("Account Found - Signed In")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .userSignedIn, object: nil)

                            }
                            break
                          case .revoked:
                              print("No Account Found")
                              fallthrough
                          case .notFound:
                               print("No Account Found")
                               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               }


                          default:
                            break
                          }

                      }
               }
   ```
3. Receive notification:

   `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(profileLaunch(_:)), name: .userSignedIn, object: nil)`

I can't tell whether the notification is not getting posted or the observer is not getting called. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax related to posting and receiving notification seems to be correct. Had you tried adding debug breakpoints to check whether the post notification statement is getting executed

Comment: Yes! Breakpoints, prints, all that. The print statements appear correctly and the breakpoints as well. It may help to know that no post or listener has worked in my app thus far if that correlates to anything

Comment: Hey Brandon. Where did you put your addObserver method?

Comment: I can put it anywhere and it will not work; viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, my won function, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

May be! delegate does not set.Hope, Here You get the answer --> [didReceiveRemoteNotification not called, iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)

Comment: thanks for the input, but I think that is a different issue