# flutter build xcode11.3 failed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

**my build  target is 8.0**
when I run flutter build iOS,I ran into the error, can someone help? thanks!!

system info: macOS catalina v10.15.2

my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
      ]
      end
    end
  end
```

my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>flutter_lim</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <key>PermissionGroupNotification</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

error output:

```
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.1.0/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionStrategy.m:71:5: warning: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:69:32: note:
    'UIRemoteNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIRemoteNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.1.0/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionStrategy.m:71:72: warning: 'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes' is
    deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to retrieve user-enabled remote notification and user notification settings [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
                                                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:229:1: note:
    'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes API_DEPRECATED("Use -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to retrieve user-enabled remote notification and user notification settings", ios(3.0, 8.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration
    [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration
    [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration
    [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mobpush_plugin-1.0.9/ios/Classes/MobpushPlugin.m:5:
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MOBFoundation.h:28:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MOBFImageGetter.h:25:4: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable,
    or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance;
       ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MOBFImageGetter.h:25:4: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance;
       ^
                    _Nullable
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MOBFImageGetter.h:25:4: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance;
       ^
                    _Nonnull
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mobpush_plugin-1.0.9/ios/Classes/MobpushPlugin.m:5:
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MOBFoundation.h:33:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MobSDK.h:108:9: warning: parameter 'data' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param data  title=标题,content=内容(type=1，返回url,type = 2时返回富文本)
            ^~~~
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation/MOBFoundation.framework/Headers/MobSDK.h:108:9: note: did you mean 'result'?
     @param data  title=标题,content=内容(type=1，返回url,type = 2时返回富文本)
            ^~~~
            result
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mobpush_plugin-1.0.9/ios/Classes/MobpushPlugin.m:223:22: warning:
    'sendMessageWithMessageType:content:space:isProductionEnvironment:extras:linkScheme:linkData:result:' is deprecated: Method discard from v2.3.0. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                [MobPush sendMessageWithMessageType:type
                         ^
    In file included from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mobpush_plugin-1.0.9/ios/Classes/MobpushPlugin.m:3:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/mob_pushsdk/MobPush/MobPush.framework/Headers/MobPush+Test.h:42:70: note:
    'sendMessageWithMessageType:content:space:isProductionEnvironment:extras:linkScheme:linkData:result:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
                                result:(void (^)(NSError *error))handler __deprecated_msg("Method discard from v2.3.0.");
                                                                         ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/mob_pushsdk/MobPush/MobPush.framework/Headers/MobPush.h:9:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    3 warnings generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/Geek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dhwtsvpdzvjexedeiokhabtbjtth/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/mobpush_plugin.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MobpushPlugin.o
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mobpush_plugin-1.0.9/ios/Classes/MobpushPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:73:53: warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'FlutterEngine *' to
    parameter of type 'NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger> * _Nonnull' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                        binaryMessenger:_headlessRunner];
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.h:1:
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:178:74: note: passing argument to parameter 'messenger' here
                          binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger;
                                                                             ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:157:103: warning: values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format
    arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead [-Wformat]
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.%lu", [[[self currentSession] configuration] identifier], [task taskIdentifier]];
                                                ~~~                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                %lu                                                       (unsigned long)
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:162:89: warning: values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format
    arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead [-Wformat]
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.%lu", [[session configuration] identifier], [task taskIdentifier]];
                                                ~~~                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                %lu                                         (unsigned long)
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:273:15: warning: unused variable 'url' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSString *url = dict[KEY_URL];
                  ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:863:52: warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURLSessionTask *' to
    parameter of type 'NSURLSessionDownloadTask *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            NSString *taskId = [self identifierForTask:task ofSession:session];
                                                       ^~~~
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:160:60: note: passing argument to parameter 'task' here
    - (NSString*)identifierForTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask*) task ofSession:(NSURLSession *)session
                                                               ^
    /Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:904:51: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                        localNotification.alertBody = _allFilesDownloadedMsg;
                                                      ^
                                                      self->
    6 warnings generated.
    4 warnings generated.
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...
    Building App.framework for arm64...

    Building App.framework for armv7...
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             65.1s
    Built to build/aot/.
    warning: parsing line table prologue at offset 0x6f697463 found unsupported version 0x00
    warning: line table parameters mismatch. Cannot emit.
    note: while processing /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/build/aot/armv7/snapshot_assembly.o
    Project /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim built and packaged successfully.
    mkdir -p /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/深度智投.app/Frameworks
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules"
    "/Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/ios/Pods/../Flutter/Flutter.framework" "/Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/深度智投.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    Flutter.framework/
    Flutter.framework/Flutter
    Flutter.framework/Info.plist
    Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

    sent 369751741 bytes  received 120 bytes  35214462.95 bytes/sec
    total size is 369706205  speedup is 1.00
    fatal error: lipo: can't write to output file: /Users/Geek/work/flutter_lim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/深度智投.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter.lipo (No space left on device)
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

#### Reproduction steps

#### Configuration

**Version:** 4.1.0  permission_handler

**Platform:** 
- [x] :iphone: iOS

when I  change ios build target to 10.0, more warning came

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454033/registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios-8-0-and-later

Comment: How did you resolve the "fluttertoast" errors? That wasn't addressed in the solution.

Comment: In my  case, there were warnings made by fluttertoast, the warning would not break the build process, you may check about the message to check about if it is real error or warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message says:

```
/Users/Geek/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.1.0/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionStrategy.m:71:5: warning: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

You have to add:

```
if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: (.Badge | .Sound | .Alert), categories: nil));
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Sound | .Alert)
}
```

There is a added issue for this, [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/191).

Comment: hh, what a coincident, it is me who put the issue. I solve this by change build target. Thank you all the same!!